# Undefined reference to sql.h functions

Tags: c++, sql, import

I am trying to connect to a sql database using ODBC in c++ and I can't call any of the functions in sql.h file: Here is my test code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;
int main(){
    SQLHANDLE SQLEnvHandle;
    SQLRETURN myRet = SQLAllocStmt(NULL,NULL);
    cout<<cos(3.0);
    return 0;
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe générer le fichier actif",
            "command": "C:\\Users\\caronfe\\AppData\\Local\\msys2\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compilateur : C:\\Users\\caronfe\\AppData\\Local\\msys2\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to compile with g++, getting this error:
`` undefined reference to `SQLAllocStmt' ``

When I switch one of the NULL parameters to an integer, the compiler gives me this error instead:
`invalid conversion from 'int' to 'SQLHDBC'`

So the compiler find the function, but still throws an undefined reference error.
The same behavior happens for other sql.h functions, but not for any other import.
Config:
I am on windows 10 and mingw64 is installed for the user only
I am using VSCode editor (Intellisense also finds the functions...)
Other codes not using sql.h compiles and execute perfectly
Compiler: g++ (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.3.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You probably need to link to some library. Perhaps `odbc32.lib`

Comment: Building a C++ program is done in multiple steps: 1) Edit the source code; Compile the source code into an object file (this is the step where the preprocessor includes header files); 3) Link object files with libraries to create the final executable program. Your error happens in the last step, probably because you don't link with the ODBC library.

Comment: ***Intellisense also finds the functions*** Intellisense in VSCode is not a good indicator of compile time problems. The settings for include paths, what files to build and what to link are completely independent of the settings in c_cpp_properties.json which configures intellisense.

Comment: True, but how could the compiler give me an error on the parameters of the function if it cannot find it?

Comment: Your problem is likely a linker problem in your `tasks.json`. You need to add additional args: to link to the odbc libraries.

Comment: The compiler can find the *declaration* of the function, as it's in the included `sql.h` header file. The declaration only tell the compiler that the function exists somewhere, and what the type of its arguments are, and what it returns. The *definition* is the implementation of the function, and it's in a library that you need to link with.

Comment: If you haven't read [this GCC with VSCode tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) I recommend you do it now. Pay close attention to the difference in purpose between the `c_cpp_properties.json` and `tasks.json` configuration files.

Comment: Thanks, but the sql.h is located in the standard include path:"C:\Users\caronfe\AppData\Local\msys2\mingw64\include\sql.h",where should be the definition?

Comment: ***where should be the definition?*** In some .lib file. On the second comment I told you to try `odbc32.lib`

Comment: It is not on my computer, but I do have odbc32.dll